# Getting values from an array throws ErrorException "Trying to get property of non-object"

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to display the keys for each event in an array.

This is the var_dump

```
PAMI\Message\ResponseResponseMessage (object) [Object ID #374][9 properties]
events: (array) [29 elements]
    0:  PAMI\Message\EventPeerEntryEvent (object) [Object ID #381][6 properties]
            rawContent:protected: (string) Event: PeerEntry
            ActionID: 1517499612.3137
            Channeltype: SIP
            ObjectName: 100
            ChanObjectType: peer
            IPaddress: -none-
            IPport: 0
            Dynamic: yes
            AutoForcerport: no
            Forcerport: yes
            AutoComedia: no
            Comedia: yes
            VideoSupport: no
            TextSupport: no
            ACL: yes
            Status: UNKNOWN
            RealtimeDevice: no
            Description: 
        channelVariables:protected: (array) [1 element]
            default: (array) [0 elements]
        lines: (array) [0 elements]
        variables: (array) [0 elements]
        keys: (array) [18 elements]
            event: (string) PeerEntry
            actionid: (string) 1517499612.3137
            channeltype: (string) SIP
            objectname: (string) 100
            chanobjecttype: (string) peer
            ipaddress: (string) -none-
            ipport: (string) 0
            dynamic: (string) yes
            autoforcerport: (string) no
            forcerport: (string) yes
            autocomedia: (string) no
            comedia: (string) yes
            videosupport: (string) no
            textsupport: (string) no
            acl: (string) yes
            status: (string) UNKNOWN
            realtimedevice: (string) no
            description: (string) 
            createdDate: (integer) 1517499612

    1: etc........

    2: etc........
```

and this is in my blade.php

```
       @foreach($data->events as $peer)
            <tr>
                <td>{{ $peer->keys->ipaddress }}</td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
        @endforeach
```

I keep getting the error

> "Trying to get property of non-object"

I know what the error means, but I don't know what I am doing wrong.

If I just do a var_dump on the $peer, I can see all the keys, but I just can not access them.

Any help would be appreciated!

Edit**
So i did a var_dump like so

```
   @foreach($data->events as $peer)
        <tr>
            <td>
            @if($peer->keys)
                {{ var_dump($peer->keys) }}
            @endif
            </td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    @endforeach
```

This is the output of dd
https://pastebin.com/0Wv4nehp

The problem now, is that I can only use "event" or "actionid"
{{ $peer->keys["event"] }}

if i try to use anything else in that array...
{{ $peer->keys["status"] }}

I get this
Undefined index: status

I at a loss for words here.

Comment: `{{ $peer->keys['ipaddress'] }}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `[]` to access array element instead of `->` which used to access object property.

```
@foreach($data->events as $peer)
        <tr>
            <td>{{ $peer->keys["ipaddress"] }}</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
@endforeach
```

If there any possibility of missing element, then you can do this-

```
@foreach($data->events as $peer)
        <tr>
             @foreach($peer->keys as $key=>$value)
               <td>{{ $value }}</td>
             @endforeach
        </tr>
@endforeach
```

Comment: So that works... but only for "event" and "actionid". Everything else in the array still gives Undefined index: channeltype or whatever else i put there. Thoughts?

Comment: could you please show us `dd($peer->keys)` , it should have worked for all though

Comment: @AlanSpurlock your code is fine, may be there is a array record where you don't have any status element

Comment: @AlanSpurlock see my updated answer, this might work for you

Comment: So that worked pretty good. But how do you narrow down a <td> to just say..... ipaddress or status?

Comment: I got it. I am using if(!empty($peer->keys['xxxx'] and it works great. Thanks!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

```
   @foreach($data->events as $peer)
        <tr>
            <td>
              @if($peer->keys)
                  {{ $peer->keys->ipaddress }}
              @endif
            </td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    @endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

In your example I see each event have many keys
You are trying to display all events and all keys for each events

```
@foreach($data->events as $peer)
    <tr>
        <td>
             @foreach($peer->keys as $key)
                 {{ $key->ipaddress }} ,
             @endforeach
        </td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

This code should display all events and ip addresses separated by comma